# Train a custom BIO Tagger with NTLK

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I have been searching for a while, but I didn't find anything about this.

I've got the following problem:
I want to train a model where for a input i get a custom BIO tag. For instance, for the input "My dad lives in Manhattan, his name is Anthony Clark", and the classes LOC and PER, the output has to be:

```
[(My, O),(dad,O), (lives, O), (in,O), (Manhattan, B-LOC), (, , O), (his,O), (name,O), (is,O), (Anthony, B-PER), (Clark,I-PER)]
```

Is it possible to do with NTLK? Which features should I include?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I didn't need NLTK for this; but the POS tagger would be useful as a feature for the training.
There are better options than using the default NLTK POs tagger, such as the Stanford Tagger or Freeling.